# Parse Error on Google Sheet pull

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I’ve setup a google form to autopopulate a google sheet, and pln to use the google sheet to autopopulate other google sheets.

I’ve been able to populate other tabs within the same sheet with the latter half of this formula:

=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15YSbXULVG7PqORsAKV43JYENZww5g6q3NrkEVcyddvc", "Master!A1:Z3000"), "Select * where B = 'Demon’s Souls' and H = 1 and J = 0", 1)

However, when I try using this in another google sheet, I get a Formula Parse error.

I’m assuming that my issue is in the Importrange section. I’ve verified address is correct, but cannot figure out why this will not work.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Am now getting a value error? Yippee

Comment: Check whether you granted permission for IMPORTRANGE() when you copied formula to new document, that's how you can get VALUE error.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess (and we can only guess if you haven't shared a link to your sheet) would be that the problem lies in the apostrophe in "Demon's Souls." You'll notice that you are using single straight quotes around the term, which is correct. But if you copy that formula elsewhere, your curly apostrophe in "Demon's" is likely getting converted to a straight apostrophe, which would cause the errors you are describing.

One possible solution is to make sure your curly apostrophe is, in fact, copied to other sheets as such. And one way to do that is to type into an empty cell at destination `=CHAR(8217)` and then copy/paste that character into the word that has the apostrophe within the formula.

Other solutions are many, but we'd need a link to your sheet, with the sharing permission set to "Anyone with the link can edit."